# JavaScript code in iframe doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe which is created after loading page. (main DOM)

```
var object_preview = $('#preview');

var iframe = $('<iframe id="preview_frame">'),
    iframe_body,
    iframe_head;

object_preview.html(iframe);

setTimeout(function() {
   var doc = iframe[0].contentWindow.document;
   iframe_body = $('body', doc);
   iframe_head = $('head', doc);
}, 1);
```

When you click on a button, in the iframe head inserted JS-code (jQuery), which must be executed within the iframe DOM.

```
$('#run').click(function() {
        iframe_body.append('<script type="text/javascript">\
                $(document).ready(function() {\
                        $(".test").click(function() { alert(true); });\
                });\           
        </script>');
});
```

Now it doesn't work. How to implement it?

Element with class .test is within iframe DOM.

HTML structure:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u provide a jsfiddle of html/js

Comment: The document within iframe has been ready for a long time before you append the script.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary `.ready` event listener.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, I tried it, doesn't work anyway.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16194680/3110982, hope it helps.