# Injecting CUSTOM JS File within an IFrame

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I want to inject a custom JS File within an IFrame (which is rendered via a Plugin)..

The below code in my Themes -> functions.php, injects my External JS File into the MAIN Document :

```
add_action('init', 'ajaxcomments_load_js', 10);
function ajaxcomments_load_js(){
        wp_enqueue_script('ajaxcomments', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/ajaxCode.js');
}
```

However, in Wordpress how can I inject JS File into a specific IFrame ?

Any help would be great. Thanks !

Comment: I think you can only do this if the iframe is within the same domain as the originating page.  **Edit:** More information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194398/inject-a-javascript-function-into-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to inject your JavaScript into an `iframe` if the `iframe` is not pointing to the domain that the page is served from.  Otherwise this is considered a security risk and any modern browser will specifically block it.  (Imagine if evilsite.com loaded yourbank.com in an `iframe` and injected JavaScript to force a bank transfer, for example).  This is just not allowed.

Otherwise - if this is a domain you control you might consider [this approach](https://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/inject-content-into-a-new-iframe/)