# Ajax request: Refused to set unsafe header

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, user-agent, http-referer

I am trying to play an audio using Google Text-To-Speech. Therefore I need to post a request to their endpoint with the `Referer` and the `User-Agent` properly set. This call should return an MP3 that I can play.

However, I get `Refused to set unsafe header` errors. This is my code. How can I do this?

```
          $.ajax({
            url: 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=Hello&tl=en&client=t',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                 xhr.setRequestHeader("Referer", "http://translate.google.com/");
                 xhr.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)");
            }, success: function(data){
                el.mp3 = new Audio(data);
                el.mp3.play();
            }
          });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Header in AJAX Request with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/add-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery)

Comment: Doesn't matter what header you set, the Google translate endpoint doesn't support CORS

Comment: From cURL it works...

Comment: @Arturo — For cURL you are making the request yourself, you aren't asking your visitor's browser to quietly do it in the background on your behalf. There are lots of extra security restrictions when you try to make other people's browsers do things.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can't. It is impossible.

The [specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader) requires that the browser abort the `setRequestHeader` method if you try to set the `Referer` header (it used to be that `User-Agent` was also forbidden but that has changed)..

If you need to set `Referer` manually then you'll need to make the request from your server and not your visitor's browser.

(That said, if you need to be deceptive about the user agent or referer then you are probably trying to use the service in a fashion that the owner of it does not want, so you should respect that and stop trying).

Note that while jQuery wraps XHR, the same rules apply to [fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name).

Comment: Not necessarily. There are a number of privacy-related situations where sending an *empty* referrer and origin are entirely reasonable. For example, suppose you have a government age verification site. A request from your server or from the client with a populated referrer and origin means the government knows exactly who visited specific sites. There's no legitimate reason for any government to know that information, so this *should* be sent anonymously, with no referrer. Of course, one could argue that this is "trying to use the service in a fashion that the owner of it does not want".  

Answer (score 3):

### Empty `Origin` and `Referer` headers with `GET XMLHttpRequest` from `<iframe>`

Well actually, it *is* possible; at least for ordinary web pages.
The trick consists in [injecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65424634/2192488) an `XMLHttpRequest`
function into an empty `<iframe>`.
The origin of an empty `<iframe>` [happens to be](https://webstersprodigy.net/2013/02/01/stripping-the-referer-in-a-cross-domain-post-request/) `about://blank`, which results in empty `Origin` and `Referer` HTTP headers.

HTML:

```html
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```js
const iframe    = document.getElementById('iframe');
const iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
const iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframeWin.document;

let script = iframeDoc.createElement('SCRIPT');

script.append(`function sendWithoutOrigin(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', url);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if(request.status === 200) {
                console.log('GET succeeded.');
            }
            else {
                console.warn('GET failed.');
            }
        }
    }
    request.send();
}`);

iframeDoc.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

JavaScript evocation:

```js
var url  = 'https://api.serivce.net/';
    url += '?api_key=' + api_write_key;
    url += '&field1=' + value;

iframeWin.sendWithoutOrigin(url);
```

Having the possibility of sending empty `Origin` and `Referer` HTTP headers is **important to safeguard privacy** when using third-party API services. There are instances where the originating domain name may reveal sensitive personal information; like being suggestive of a certain medical condition for example. Think in terms of [https://hypochondriasis-support.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypochondriasis) :-D

The code was tested by inspecting the requests in a `.har` file, saved from the `Network` tab in the <kbd>F12</kbd> Developer View in Vivaldi.

No attempt in setting the `User-Agent` header was made. Please, comment if this also works.

Answer (score 1):

There are some header, which browser doesn't allow programmer to set its value in any of the javascript framework (like jQuery, Angular, etc.) or `XMLHttpRequest` ; while making AJAX request. These are called the forbidden headers: [Forbidden Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name)