# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set to * - but can't acces images anywhere in HTML img tag

Tags: ajax, postman, http-status-code-403

Just faced an issue with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS policy.

I load a link `https://kiszo.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/14-1-scaled-e1616096596896.jpg`

In postman i can see that there is an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set to `*`

[image]

But nevertheless i cannot use this image on any other domain in an img tag, because i get a 403 error.

I always get a 403 and no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

[image]

Its a CORS policy issue or something else?

Answer (score -1):

So the issue was with the Cloudflare Hotlink Prevention:
[image: https://kiszo.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/szijjarto-1.jpg]

I tried to change the `Referer` header, [but that is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143776/ajax-request-refused-to-set-unsafe-header#answer-33144144:%7E:text=You%20can%27t.%20It%20is%20impossible.)

For me this worked:
try diabling Cloudflare Hotlink Prevention, and check the pageurl in the Cloudflare Dashboard also.