# How to control jQuery on my page from iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I need to control jQuery codes in iframe content, is that possible?

For example, Ihave a website like **www.example.com**, and this site has an iframe like:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example2.com/test.php" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="550"></iframe>
```

I want to add jQuery codes in the iframe (i mean test.php) and control my main page (www.example.com). Can someone help me with that?

Comment: might be a repeat question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery I haven't yet tried it but you could try this with custom query callbacks such as `$('body').trigger('customcallbackname');` from within the iframe and in example.com you'd have a function looking at the iframe body using jquery `.on`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inject a javascript function into an Iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194398/inject-a-javascript-function-into-an-iframe)