# How to append <script> tags in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, append, script-tag

I am trying to get  tags appended into iframe but jQuery seems to be deleting the tags automatically. I've done some research and found out that this is to keep the DOM clean.

Is there anyway to get around this somehow?

---

My HTML code:

```
<div class="card-body">
<div class="sources">
    <textarea class="col-md-4 innerbox html editorviewfont"></textarea>
    <textarea class="col-md-4 innerbox css editorviewfont"></textarea>
    <textarea class="col-md-4 innerbox js editorviewfont"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 innerbox preview editorviewfont">
    <iframe id="previewtarget">
         <div id="source" contenteditable="true">
             <!DOCTYPE html>
             <html lang="en">
                 <head>
                     <meta charset="utf-8">
                 </head>
                 <body>
                 </body>
             </html>
         </div>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code

```
$(function(){
function GetHtml(){
    var html = $('.html').val();
    return html;
}
function GetCSS(){
    var Css = $('.css').val();
    return Css;
}
function GetJS(){
    var js = $('.js').val();
    return js;
}
$('.innerbox').live("keyup",function(){
    var targetp = $('#previewtarget') [0].contentWindow.document;
    targetp.open();
    targetp.close();

    var gethtml = GetHtml();
    var getcss = GetCSS();
    var getjs = GetJS();

    var javascriptinject = document.createElement("script");

    javascriptinject.src = getjs;

    $('body',targetp).append(gethtml);
    $('head',targetp).append('<style>' + getcss + '</style>');
    $('head',targetp).append(javascriptinject);
})
});
```

Comment: umm `.live()` has been deprecated for like 10 years ...

Comment: I've already dealt with that problem. Everything is working except for appending the javascript

Answer (score 0):

Are you in control of both the domains ? The one that has the Iframe, and the one with the content of the Iframe ?

Maybe someone can correct me, but I think you will run into Cross Site Scripting issues when trying to perform script injection into an Iframe that is not in the same domain.

More info can be found on this post:

[inject a javascript function into an Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194398/inject-a-javascript-function-into-an-iframe)

Comment: Its all in one domain. Im trying to create a sandbox snippetcode tool. There are 3 textareas one for html, one for css and one for javascript. The html and css load in just fine but when trying to load the javascript the script tags will automatically be deleted

Comment: @WiboKuipers What happens when you instead of creating an 'script element' wrap your 'getjs' string inside two (string) script tags ? That way you can put a string inside the text field. Just spit balling here.